# Deploying app with private info on Heroku

Tags: mongodb, heroku, github

I have a Node project on Github which I deploy on Heroku and use MongoDB for database needs.
I have a URL from Mongo, which I connect to using the username and password. It all works perfectly when I run it on my local system, 'cause I can hardcode my username and password (or even use process.env.USER_NAME).

My question is, how do I pass in these values on Heroku. It is synced with my github and I don't want to make my user name and password public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use environment variables.

This can be done from within each Heroku app

1: Go to your app's settings: `https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/:yourApp/settings`
[image]

2: Click `Reveal Config Variables` and you will see an area to add or edit your environment variables
[image]

3: Within your app you will have access to these variables by accessing your processs.

```
var dbURL = process.env.databaseUrl,
    dbUsername = process.env.dbUsername,
    dbPassword = process.env.dbPassword;
```

4: For development purposes you will still need to keep those variables in an env variable. Install the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) npm module.

```
npm install dotenv

// appRoot/.env

    dbURL=localhost:27017
    dbUsername=tacoman
    dbPassword=ILoveTacos

// approot/server.js

    require('dotenv').load();
```